# OneDrive REST API - CORS POST request

Tags: javascript, cors, onedrive

I'm trying to create a folder using the OneDrive REST API following the official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659743.aspx#create_a_folder).
I have implemented it as AJAX request in JavaScript, which results in a CORS request in the browser.

As expected, the browser sends a first OPTIONS request  with the relevant headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

The response headers, however, does not include *authorization* as allowed header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, HEAD, MOVE, COPY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:2592000
```

Consequently, the browser (Chromium 34 in this case) logs an error in the console and does not submit the POST request, since it is not allowed to add the *Authorization* header:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive. Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Is there any way to get around this issue? From my understanding this is a server issue, since the documentation explicitly asks for this header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to provide the access_token as a query parameter like the "Delete a Folder" example (and don't provide it via the Authorization header).